# Modules and classes using JSDoc + RequireJS + BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, jsdoc

I'm trying to create a documentation for my system but something's always wrong.

In the following, my Class appear in the module MyModule, perfect! But my function doesn't appear in the documentation!

Do you have any idea where the problem is coming from?

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {
    'use strict';

/**
 * MyModule
 *
 * @module MyModule
 */

var MyModule = {};

/**
 * Class description
 *
 * @class MyModule.View
 * @extends Backbone.View
 * @memberOf module:MyModule
 * @abstract
 */

MyModule.View = Backbone.View.extend(

   /** @lends MyModule.View  */

   {

    /**
     * myFunction1
     *
     * @param {object} hello Hello World!
     */

    myFunction1: function(hello) { }


   }

});

/**
 * Class description
 *
 * @class MyModule.Model
 * @extends Backbone.Model
 * @memberOf module:MyModule
 * @abstract
 */

MyModule.Model = Backbone.Model.extend();
    //etc...
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prefix the name passed to `@lends` with the module name. See the `@lends` statement in this snipped I adapted from the code in your question:

```
MyModule.View = Backbone.View.extend(
    /** @lends module:MyModule.MyModule.View  */
    {

    /**
     * myFunction1
     *
     * @param {object} hello Hello World!
     */
    myFunction1: function(hello) { }
   });
```

With the `@lends` above, I'm able to get `myFunction1` to show up, properly documented.